# Query to get lowest value that's greater than zero ans is not NULL

Tags: mysql

I've got a query:

```
SELECT
    taskDeadline,
    subtasksDeadline,
    REPLACE(
        LEAST(
            COALESCE(t.deadline, 2147483647),
            COALESCE(sub.deadline, 2147483647)
        ), 2147483647, NULL
    ) AS Deadline
FROM
    tasks t
    LEFT OUTER JOIN subtasks sub ON sub.task_id = t.id
```

This produces a result like this:

```
taskDeadline | subtasksDeadline | Deadline
1338501600   | 1333058400       | 1333058400
1334268000   | NULL             | 1334268000
NULL         | 1328050800       | 1328050800
NULL         | NULL             | NULL
1353798000   | 0                | 0
0            | 1353798000       | 0
```

I'm almost there. I've used 2147483647 as the maximum value of the data type (Mysql INT), the only problem I still have, is that if I've two values of which one is 0, I want to get the other value. I've spend some time but cannot get there. Can somebody shed a light on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or just add NULLIF to your existing COALESCE -

```
SELECT
    taskDeadline,
    subtasksDeadline,
    NULLIF(
        LEAST(
            COALESCE(NULLIF(t.deadline, 0), 2147483647),
            COALESCE(NULLIF(sub.deadline, 0), 2147483647)
        ), 2147483647
    ) AS Deadline
FROM
    tasks t
    LEFT OUTER JOIN subtasks sub ON sub.task_id = t.id
```

Comment: Quick and easy. I prefer this solution. Didn't know about NULLIF, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a case statement?

```
SELECT
    taskDeadline,
    subtasksDeadline,
    CASE
        WHEN t.deadline IS NULL AND sub.deadline IS NULL THEN NULL
        WHEN t.deadline IS NULL THEN sub.deadline
        WHEN sub.deadline IS NULL THEN t.deadline
        WHEN t.deadline > sub.deadline THEN sub.deadline
        WHEN sub.deadline > t.deadline THEN t.deadline
        WHEN sub.deadline = t.deadline THEN sub.deadline -- or this could be t.deadline
     END AS Deadline
FROM
    tasks t
    LEFT OUTER JOIN subtasks sub 
        ON sub.task_id = t.id
```

Comment: For more info:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case

Comment: I've always thought CASE WHEN would be slow. That's why I skipped this option.

Comment: Depends on the size of your data set.  It does exactly what you need for this particular problem and is also a lot more readable.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you don't want zero values for `t.deadline` and `sub.deadline` if zero is the least. So you can convert 0 to NULL, which will be squeezed out of the `COALESCE`

```
SELECT
    taskDeadline,
    subtasksDeadline,
    REPLACE(
        LEAST(
            COALESCE(IF(t.deadline = 0, NULL, t.deadline), 2147483647),
            COALESCE(IF(sub.deadline = 0, NULL, sub.deadline), 2147483647)
        ), 2147483647, NULL
    ) AS Deadline
FROM
    tasks t
    LEFT OUTER JOIN subtasks sub ON sub.task_id = t.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this query -

```
SELECT
    taskDeadline,
    subtasksDeadline,
    LEAST(
      IF(t.deadline = 0 OR t.deadline IS NULL, sub.deadline, t.deadline),
      IF(sub.deadline = 0 OR sub.deadline IS NULL, t.deadline, sub.deadline)
    ) AS Deadline
FROM
    tasks t
    LEFT OUTER JOIN subtasks sub ON sub.task_id = t.id
```