# Mysql LEAST() greater than 0

Tags: mysql

i have a table with prices and i would like to create a view on the table with the lowest price.

My Table has for exmaple the columns price1,price2.

I thought i could to it with LEAST()

e.g. select least(price1,price2) from pricelist

but it should only consider prices greater than 0 or not null.

Can I do this with LEAST()?

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Query to get lowest value that's greater than zero ans is not NULL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684757/query-to-get-lowest-value-thats-greater-than-zero-ans-is-not-null)

Answer (score 2):

One must be careful, because LEAST() returns NULL if either comparator is NULL.

```
SELECT NULLIF(LEAST(
    COALESCE(NULLIF(price1,0),999999999),
    COALESCE(NULLIF(price2,0),999999999)),
999999999) AS least_price 
FROM pricelist
```

I assume prices can be NULL, zero, or greater than zero, but not less than zero. I use NULLIF to force the price to NULL if it is zero. Then use COALESCE to force a NULL to be a very large value, which is surely greater than the other value.

Compare the two using LEAST.

If both of the prices were originally NULL or zero, then the comparison returns the very large value. This is probably not what you want, so use NULLIF again, to make that NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure for least function  to restrict 0 alternatively you can use case expression for your 2 price columns

```
select 
case when price1 = 0 or price1 is null then price2
     when price2 = 0 or price2 is null then price1
     else least(price1,price2)
end as price
from table
```