# How to get least/min value from multiple columns but ignore 0 as min/least value using mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to fetch the result from 16 columns to find which column has the minimum value but that minimum value shouldn't be 0.

so I have tried my query something like below based on some suggestions but it doesn't work for me as it returns 0.

```sql
SELECT least(
    IFNULL(col_1,0),
    IFNULL(col_2,0),
    IFNULL(col_3,0),
    IFNULL(col_4,0),
    IFNULL(col_5,0),
    IFNULL(col_6,0),
    IFNULL(col_7,0),
    IFNULL(col_8,0),
    IFNULL(col_9,0),
    IFNULL(col_10,0),
    IFNULL(col_11,0),
    IFNULL(col_12,0),
    IFNULL(col_13,0),
    IFNULL(col_14,0),
    IFNULL(col_15,0),
    IFNULL(col_16,0)) as lowest
FROM `my_date_table` 
where date_id = '108'
```

Thanks and please don't mark as repeat question as I already go through some of the stack questions but couldn't find the right solution that I can apply on my query on php/mysql.

Comment: `but that minimum value shouldn't be 0` ... can you explain what this actually means?

Comment: I think it means the least value, not including any zero values.

Comment: Is there a maximum possible value of the columns? You could use `LEAST(IF(col_1 = 0, maximum+1, col_1), ...)`

Comment: A similar one for your reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684757/query-to-get-lowest-value-thats-greater-than-zero-ans-is-not-null

Comment: sorry, I cant use any maximum possible value of the column & @RevathiGanesh the reference you provided is not returning me the wrong result.

Comment: Are you sure you have a good data structure? It seems like an odd thing for a data table to have 16 date columns which you want to run min on.

Comment: hi @Jack I do have and the 16 columns are not dates but it contain the data like numbers. Actual issue is not the table structure but to sort out this kind of situation

Comment: hey @Barmar can you please explain your solution? I mean why you are incrementing maximum+1 and secondly how many "if" condition do I have to place can you please write your query in full. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there's a maximum possible value for the columns, you can replace any zero values with something above this maximum before calling `LEAST`. Then it will return the value of the least column that's lower than this maximum.

In the code below, I assume `999999` is large enough.

```
SELECT least(
    IF(IFNULL(col_1,0) = 0, 999999, col_1),
    IF(IFNULL(col_2,0) = 0, 999999, col_2),
    IF(IFNULL(col_3,0) = 0, 999999, col_3),
    IF(IFNULL(col_4,0) = 0, 999999, col_4),
    IF(IFNULL(col_5,0) = 0, 999999, col_5),
    IF(IFNULL(col_6,0) = 0, 999999, col_6),
    IF(IFNULL(col_7,0) = 0, 999999, col_7),
    IF(IFNULL(col_8,0) = 0, 999999, col_8),
    IF(IFNULL(col_9,0) = 0, 999999, col_9),
    IF(IFNULL(col_10,0) = 0, 999999, col_10),
    IF(IFNULL(col_11,0) = 0, 999999, col_11),
    IF(IFNULL(col_12,0) = 0, 999999, col_12),
    IF(IFNULL(col_13,0) = 0, 999999, col_13),
    IF(IFNULL(col_14,0) = 0, 999999, col_14),
    IF(IFNULL(col_15,0) = 0, 999999, col_15),
    IF(IFNULL(col_16,0) = 0, 999999, col_16)) as lowest
FROM `my_date_table` 
where date_id = '108'
```

Comment: just a question tho, what if my max value and min value are the same like for example, someone did the entry of max value as 20 and min value is also 20 then do you think your solution will work? - Just asking

Comment: It will return 20.

Comment: `999999` is supposed to be something that can't actually be in the table.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an easy task. You cannot simply turn all `0`s to `NULL`s since `LEAST()` returns `NULL` if any of its arguments is `NULL`.

If you know in advance the maximum value across all columns, you can use the trick commented by [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar).

Else, assuming that you have a primary key called `id` in the table, a (suboptimal) solution  solution could be to unpivot the table using `UNION ALL`, while turning `0` values to `NULL` values; then, you can take advantage of aggregate function `MIN()`, which ignores `NULL` values.

Example query for 5 columns:

```
SELECT id, MIN(col) lowest
FROM (
    SELECT id, NULLIF(col1, 0) col FROM mytable
    UNION ALL SELECT id, NULLIF(col2, 0) FROM mytable
    UNION ALL SELECT id, NULLIF(col3, 0) FROM mytable
    UNION ALL SELECT id, NULLIF(col4, 0) FROM mytable
    UNION ALL SELECT id, NULLIF(col5, 0) FROM mytable
) x
GROUP BY id
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vgKcu441jai3VQekhbgLSe/0)**

Sample data:

```
| id  | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 |
| --- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- |
| 1   | 1    | 2    | 3    | 4    | 5    |
| 2   | 0    | 6    | 7    | 8    | 9    |
| 3   | 0    | 10   | 11   | 12   |      |
```

Results:

```
| id  | lowest |
| --- | ------ |
| 1   | 1      |
| 2   | 6      |
| 3   | 10     |
```

Comment: hummm....kind of work but looking for something easy solution as just imagine for 16 columns to do this.

Comment: @Jimil: I do understand... But as of now there is no shorter or more elegant solution that I can think of...

Comment: Its working but do you think it will increase the load of query

Answer (score 0):

One relatively simple (but expensive) method is to unpivot and aggregation:

```
select min(col), max(col)
from ((select col_1 as col from t) union all
      (select col_2 as col from t) union all
      . . .
      (select col_16 as col from t) 
     ) c
where col <> 0;
```

If you want to express this using `least()`, you can use `coalesce()` *with* `nullif()`:

```
select nullif( least( coalesce(nullif(col_1, 0), 999999),
                      coalesce(nullif(col_2, 0), 999999),
                      . . .
                    ), 999999
              )
```

This assumes that you have some reasonable maximum value to use for `999999`.

Comment: This is essentially mine and GMB's answers. But your code doesn't handle actual NULL values in the table.